# Not to trigger circleci workflow when changes are from static files

Tags: devops, circleci, cicd, circleci-2.0, circleci-orb

I am having a workflow that i only want to trigger if the changes are not only coming from static files like below in codemagic.

```
jobs:
  my_job:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "Hello, world!"
    when:
      changeset:
        includes:
          - '.'
        excludes:
          - '**/*.md'
          - 'docs/**'
```

I do know that CircleCI doesn't support `changeset, includes, excludes`

In code magic, the above code could do the magic of not triggering the workflow if the changes are coming from the static files and i want to implement the same thing in CircleCI because my workflow is huge and there is no need to run a workflow if the codebase has not changed maybe what is changed is just some bunch of static files.

I am aware of CircleCI [dynamic configuration](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config/#what-is-the-continuation-orb) and [Path filtering](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/path-filtering)but that's not what i am looking out to implement because my repo is not a mono-repo and i am not aiming at running the workflow based on modules but i want everything to run except when the changes are only from static files set in the excludes params